# Javascript statement document.getElementById('').style.display = "inline"; is effect later on when I open editor(Div) again

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

My requirement is to click on "save" button below thing should happen,

1. save button and cancel button become hide
2. loading button display on the place of "save" and "cancel" buttons.
   As my implementation when I click on "save" button current div hide, but when I again open that editor(Div)
   I can see "save" and "cancel" are hidden and "loading" button is displayed.
   Means style.display statement code does not affect immediately.

I want this happen on first time when click on "save".
Below is capture image
when i click on save button

[image]

when I open editor (div) the second time

[image]

Please help to achieve this. I have attached saveEditor() code for reference

```
   function saveEditor() {
    document.getElementById('cancelButton').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('saveButton').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('loadButton').style.display = "inline";
    save2DDrawing();    
    var json = exportInformation();
    console.log("exportInformation = "+json);
    surfaceEditor.style.display = "none";     
    loadUpdatedEnclosure(json);
}
```

Comment: Are you setting some state for those buttons when they getting hide?

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: @ Salman Bukhari Yes when I open editor again then I display them again

Comment: Why not update the button state at the time it matters? Like when the editor window opens / loading finishes? https://jsfiddle.net/tvf8rn62/